# Entity Framework mocking requires global context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have recently began to dig into Entity Framework unit-testing with Entity Framework 6 mocking.

I have noticed the following thing:

Entity Framework mocking forces me to create a global context in my BL class, for example:

```
public class RefundRepayment : IDisposable
{
    protected DbContext _dbContext = new DbContext();

    /* more properties and class code */

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _dbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I can't quite figure it out, as I'd rather implement the `using` statement in every method in order to deal with the `DbContext`, my code will look like:

```
public class RefundRepayment
{
    /* more properties and class code */
    public void AccessDb() 
    {
        using(DbContext dbContext = new DbContext())
        {
            /* db code here */
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any specific reason why should we initialize a global context instead of implementing the `using` statement?

Comment: ideally that context should be injected into the dependent class and its life cycle managed by the DI container. In fact it could be argued that it should be abstracted out as it is also an implementation concern.

Comment: That means creating a class solely for the context implementation?

Comment: More like creating a class solely to wrap the context and expose only what is needed by BL class to perform its function. It should not even know or care that a context exists.

Comment: Just note that if unit testing your code in isolation requires you to mock entity framework then there is something wrong with the current design and that it should be reviewed.

Comment: It is more of a need to test our entity framework code, we have pretty nice amount of persistence code that need to be tested in order to make it easier for us to develop.

Comment: To test EF code then you need to do integration testing with a connection to an actual test database.

Comment: We already have the test DB :)

Comment: In order to maintain ACID you need to have a global context to run multiple operations. Creating context is always is expensive

Comment: DbContexts should always be within using() clauses. Ideally you inject them (this simplifies the atomicity as well) or use a central place to return contexts for you. Note however that the **creation** of DbContext instances is very cheap - model creation, connection handling and query computing will be the expensive parts. Also note that relying solely on integration testing for EF is bad since these are expensive, hard to maintain and test cross dependencies rather than specific units - which may point to a missing abstraction layer in your code base.

Comment: EF is implementation details of data access layer. So you should test it against database EF can deal with (in-memory database?) _We already have the test DB_ - why you need unit tests then?

Comment: Because we want to test our DB access code for the correct values, we work with millions of records and this will make ease with us in our development process.

Comment: @BarrJ, but you said you already have tests for DB. You trying to mock implementation details, which will lead to difficult to configure and maintain tests. If you try to mock DbContext you end up rewriting tests every time you change a query even query behaviour remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to be using DI (via ninject, Unity, Core, etc) to pull this off.

Let me show you a simple sample of an EF GetAll() testing my MVC controller.

```
[Fact]
public void GetAllOk()
{
    // Arrange

    // Act
    var result = _controller.GetAll() as OkObjectResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    var recordList = result.Value as List<DTO.Account>;
    Assert.NotNull(recordList);
    Assert.Equal(4, recordList.Count);
}
```

It relies on this startup code...

```
public class AccountsControllerTests
{
    DatabaseFixture _fixture;
    AccountsControllerV1 _controller;

    public AccountsControllerTests(DatabaseFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
        _controller = new AccountsControllerV1(_fixture._uow);
    }
```

What is DatabaseFixture?  Glad you asked...

```
public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    public ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> _options;
    public IUoW _uow;

    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
        var x = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Tests.json", optional : true)
            .Build();

        _options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "ProviderTests")
            .Options;

        _context = new ApplicationDbContext(_options);
        _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        Initialize();

        _uow = new UoW(_context);
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        _context.Accounts.Add(new Entities.Account() { AccountNumber = "Number 1", AccountID = "", AccountUniqueID = "" });
        _context.Accounts.Add(new Entities.Account() { AccountNumber = "Number 2", AccountID = "", AccountUniqueID = "" });
        _context.Accounts.Add(new Entities.Account() { AccountNumber = "Number 3", AccountID = "", AccountUniqueID = "" });
        _context.Accounts.Add(new Entities.Account() { AccountNumber = "Number 4", AccountID = "", AccountUniqueID = "" });
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Clean Up
        _context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }
}

[CollectionDefinition("Database Collection")]
public class DatabaseCollection : ICollectionFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
}
```

A few definitions used in the above code.  I used a Unit of Work Pattern that contains references to all my EF repositories.  I kept Entity (Database) classes and DTO (Data Transfer Object) Classes separate.  I used an in-memory replacement for the EF database that I initialize at the beginning of each run and/or test so that my data is always *known*.  I inject the Database Fixture into my test class (not each test) so I am not creating/destroying constantly.  Then I create my controller passing in my database UoW definition.

You're *real* controller requires injection of the UoW container you've created with the *real* database.  You are merely substituting a controlled database environment for your test.

```
public AccountsControllerV1(IUoW uow)
{
    _uow = uow;
}
```

And yes, I use versioning for the sharp-eyed.  And yes, this is a Core 2 example.  Still applicable for EF 6, just need 3rd party DI ;)

And the controller method I am testing?

```
[HttpGet("accounts", Name ="GetAccounts")]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    try
    {
        var recordList = _uow.Accounts.GetAll();

        List<DTO.Account> results = new List<DTO.Account>();
        if (recordList != null)
        {
            results = recordList.Select(r => Map(r)).ToList();
        }

        log.Info($"Providers: GetAccounts: Success: {results.Count} records returned");
        return Ok(results);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error($"Providers: GetAccounts: Failed: {ex.Message}");
        return BadRequest($"Providers: GetAccounts: Failed: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```