# How to mock entities in ASPNET?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mocking

I need to create a data mock for a demo without access to the database server. How I could start creating it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework mocking requires global context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025368/entity-framework-mocking-requires-global-context)

Comment: Please specify what you already have tried, otherwise we assume you want a general advice which is too broad for a question on SO and can't be answered here. But google has sufficient material on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Dependency Injection, you could use an interface and have a mock object implement the interface to return mock data:

```
public interface IDataProvider
{
    object GetData();
}

public class Database : IDataProvider
{
    public object GetData()
    {
        // interact with database to get data

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class MockDatabase : IDataProvider
{
    public object GetData()
    {
        return new List<string>
        {
            "some_mock_data"
        };
    }
}
```

Then in your Dependency Injection setup code, you'd register the `MockDatabase` implementation instead of the `Database` implementation.

```
// services.AddSingleton<IDataProvider, Database>();
services.AddSingleton<IDataProvider, MockDatabase>();
```